# How does DecimalNumberByAdding work?

Tags: objective-c, ios, c, xcode, nsdecimalnumber

I have a situation which I need to add two NSDecimals  and this is the code that I have:

```
NSDecimalNumber *total = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:@"0"];
for (Product* product in cartItems) {
    NSDecimalNumber *prodPrice = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] init];
    prodPrice = product.price;
    total = [total decimalNumberByAdding:prodPrice];
}
return total;
```

It is completely working when I try to add two numbers such as 0.01 and 0.02 and it is giving me the 0.03.

But when I use a whole number it doesn't work. As an example when I try to add 0.01 and 1, it give me a negative number as a result. Can anyone help me with this issue?

Thanks

Comment: what is "`product.price`" declared as?

Comment: It is NSDecimal as well.

Comment: There is a big difference between NSDecimalNumber and NSDecimal...

Comment: How are you checking that product.price is what you think it is and how are you examining the final total?  Also what is the negative number you get?

Comment: I'm debugging it in the loop and the negative number is -0.000000...

Comment: Toss in a NSLog of both total and prodPrice, run your test, and add the logging output to the question.  BTW, the alloc/init of prodPrice is completely useless.

Answer (score 1):

I modified your loop slightly. The assignment productPrice = product.price is surely wrong in your code. Look at this:

```
NSArray *cartItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @".01", nil];
NSDecimalNumber *total = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:@"0"];

for (NSString *price in cartItems) {
    NSDecimalNumber *prodPrice = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:price];
    total = [total decimalNumberByAdding:prodPrice];
}
NSLog(@"Total: %@", total);
```

returns

```
 2012-09-13 15:04:03.815 Searcher[69779:f803] TotalL 1.01
```

Comment: This solution works fine but it's not working in some specific situations.

Comment: For example when I add 1 and 1.06 it shows me 1.05 as a result which is wrong!

Comment: So if I take the loop above and make the two numbers 1 and 1.06 the result will be 1.05? I think not.